# How can I convert mysql 8.0 to 5.7?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mysql-5.7

I have a WordPress project using `MySql 8.0` and tried this project in `localhost`. Now when I try to throw it to server it gives `mysql version error`. Is this a database made with `8.0` or how can I convert it to `5.7`?

Comment: Please always show us ALL the error message so we have a better idea of what is actually going wrong

Comment: There is no way to convert the version of software, although the best approach would be to take a backup of your database as `.sql` file. Then uninstall `MySql 8.0` and install whichever version you want to try. Also you might want to [check](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/find-mysql-version) your `phpMyAdmin` sql version. The error can be that your WordPress plugin is not compatible with your `phpMyAdmin` sql version.

Comment: Does my sql file work correctly with version 5.7 or do I need to modify my sql file?